# How can I scrape the content present on a WAVE validator page to appear on my page?

Tags: screen-scraping

I've tried fopen, fread, file_get_contents, curl, and none of those work.  I keep getting Forbidden errors.  There has got to be a way around it.  Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iframes is not scraping per se but you could use it:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1877968/edit

Just point the src attribute to the page your scraping.

Remarks:
How does one escape tags here in stack overflow?